# How do I force terraform to reset it's state?

Tags: terraform

I accidentally used the wrong minor version and now I can't do anything.

```
Error: 
Terraform doesn't allow running any operations against a state
that was written by a future Terraform version. The state is
reporting it is written by Terraform '0.11.14'
```

I just want to reset my terraform state so that I can use the proper version.

Comment: What version do you want to use? If the state file has increased by a major version then it's probably hosed. Either roll back the state file (if you're using S3 then this is why they recommend setting versioning on the bucket) or just delete the state file and reimport everything manually.

Comment: If it's only a minor change you can try manually editing the state file to set it to your version and see if Terraform will work with it. Odd things may happen though which is why Terraform is so strict about versions of Terraform matching or exceeding the state file version

Answer (score 0):

If you keep remote state, and you have it versioned (and I would strongly suggest that you do both), it may be a simple revert to an older version. But I presume you wouldn't be asking this question if it were so simple.

So, Terraform state is just a trivial JSON file and there's no integrity checking on it - for better or for worse. Try editing the state file directly, run `terraform plan` with the right version and see what gives. Most likely it will just work, but worst case you'll get an error, so it's well worth a shot.

That said, if your config ran just fine with a newer version of Terraform, why not **just roll with it**? I'd generally advise using the newest version of Terraform available that's compatible with your code, and changing your code to be compatible with the newest version of Terraform available for download.

In the future, you may want to come up with a policy and procedure on how to manage and update Terraform versions. This is something I've been trying to solve with the [Terraform CI/CD tool I'm building](https://spacelift.io) (in private beta for now, feel free to join the waitlist) and here's [the doc](https://docs.spacelift.io/concepts/version-management) that describes the solution in more detail. But the gist is - and you can use it with any CI/CD platform where you can put the version of Terraform in your job definition file (eg. CircleCI) - that you try always running `terraform plan` with a newer Terraform version in a feature branch, see the outcome and fix any incompatibilities before merging version bump to the main branch where code changes trigger `terraform apply`.